# Проблема со сборкой mxe

Tags: linux, linux-mint, qt6, icu

Собирал через mxe qt6-qtbase, проблема возникла на сборке icu4c для `i686-w64-mingw32.static`. В логах указано:

```
i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++ --std=gnu++0x -W -Wall -pedantic -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -mthreads    -o ../../bin/makeconv.exe gencnvex.o genmbcs.o makeconv.o ucnvstat.o -L../../lib "-licutu" -L../../lib "-licuin" -L../../lib "-licuuc" -L../../stubdata "-licudt" -lpthread -lm -lstdc++

/opt/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ld: cannot find -licutu: Нет такого файла или каталога

/opt/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ld: cannot find -licuin: Нет такого файла или каталога

/opt/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ld: cannot find -licuuc: Нет такого файла или каталога

/opt/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ld: cannot find -licudt: Нет такого файла или каталога
```

Разбирался в чем проблема, выяснилось что если изменить вышеописанную команду:

```
i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++ --std=gnu++0x -W -Wall -pedantic -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -mthreads    -o ../../bin/makeconv.exe gencnvex.o genmbcs.o makeconv.o ucnvstat.o **-L../../lib/"-licutu" -L../../lib/"-licuin" -L../../lib/"-licuuc" -L../../stubdata/"-licudt"** -lpthread -lm -lstdc++
```

то эти библиотеки по крайней мере обнаруживаются (проверял просто запихнув символьную ссылку на `i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++` в папку и пытаясь это выполнить)

Проблема в основном в том, что когда я выполняю `sudo make icu4c` вся директория `tmp-icu4c-i686-w64-mingw32.static` собирается заново и я не знаю что и где мне надо заменить чтобы проверить догадку

Comment: не надо запускать сборку от имени пользователя root.

Comment: У меня mxe в /opt лежит, без root не работает. Да и изначально я собирал в home, та же проблема была, что описана в вопросе.

Comment: Как вариант можете попробовать мой https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2 Там проблем со сборкой зависимостей не бывает, потому что они качаются уже собранные.

Answer (score 1):

Переключись на другой коммит:

```
$ git checkout -f bd55
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Да, без последних коммитов, проблем со сборкой icu4c не возникает